# Android SQLite Database Greek Character

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working with an SQLite database, built in my Win PC using RazorSQL.
This db contains greek characters, and all queries in my PC returns proper format.

I copy the db from my PC to the Android emulator and start using it, but varchar field values containing Greek characters are displayed as '?'.

Comment: Check whether a hardcoded greek string displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which font you are trying to use, it may not map to the greek characters.  The default font for Android is here http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Droid+Sans.  I'm not an expert in Greek, but I would try changing to a greek font and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again with your responses.
The problem is with RazorSQL. (Already post it to Razor)
I used SQLiteman to populate the DB, and everything works fine.